# Why is my array empty by the time that I console log it, and how can I fix this issue?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I'm assuming my array is empty because it takes time for the database to return the data that I'm needing and the function is running before data is being pushed to my array. But how can I wait for the data so that I can use it later on?

number.phoneNumber is working correctly so I'm assuming the push is working correctly.

```
MongoClient.connect(url, (err, client) => {
    var db = client.db('covid-poke-numbers');
    db.collection('phone-numbers').find().forEach(number => {
        phoneNumbers.push(number.phoneNumber);
    })
    client.close();
});

consoleLogNumbers();

function consoleLogNumbers() {
    console.log(phoneNumbers);
}
```

Comment: The dup target mainly talks about ajax, but the problem really is the same. You have an async call and you're trying to use its results before they are ready.

Comment: Linked another, more specific to this problem